# How can I disable "resource script was not created using Microsoft Visual Studio" warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I use pre-build hook to update version in my Win32 C++ application's RC file. When I attempt to save any edit in Visual Studio's resources editor, I get this prompt telling that changes I made to the file are not what VS expects to see inside.
[Visual Studio warning prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjCeH.png)
If I agree to replace the file, all my changes made to automatize revision number incremention will be thrown away and I will have to restore them manually.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 v17.5.4. The solution **does not** use MFC/ATL.

I have tried looking through settings in Tools - Options of Visual Studio, as well as searching by 'resource' word in 'Search Options' field. Nothing related to resource editor I could find.

Comment: if you look at the RC and H you'll see defines and ifdefs like `APSTUDIO_INVOKED` that tell VS how to manage resources in its resource editor.  It sounds like you are making changes that contradict those defines.  One way around this is to add a second RC file to the project that is not edited by VS and place your version resource in that.

Comment: @DaveS, do I need to `#include` the second RC file? If I do that, Visual Studio opens the main RC file, the changes are getting saved, but the `#include` is gone, making the `VERSIONINFO` block back to its 'calculated' value.

Comment: there's a way to add an RC not managed by app studio. but I did it 8 years ago in VS 2013 so I'm not sure how it's done in  VS 2022.  It will appear in the main RC as something like `3 TEXTINCLUDE BEGIN "\r\n" "#include ""res\\MyAppName.rc2""\0" END`

Comment: @DaveS, it actually worked. Also, I had my RC file structure damaged, `#include <winres.h>` was missing from `2 TEXTINCLUDE`, making RC file error on opening in the editor every time unless I manually add the line back.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments given by [Dave S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287427/dave-s), I applied the following changes:

1. `VERSIONINFO` resource with my build number incremention was separated into another `versioninfo.rc2` file.
2. Opened **Resource View**, right-clicked my main RC file and chose **Resource Includes**.
3. In **Compile-Time Directives**, inserted `#include "src/rc2/versioninfo.rc2"` line.
4. **Read-only symbol directives** were also missing in my case, so I restored it by inserting `#include <winres.h>`.

Now the build number incrementing works as expected.

Reference: [Microsoft Learn — How to: Include Resources at Compile Time (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-include-resources-at-compile-time)